# How can we check that a binary EXE (PE) is COM Exe or Win32 Exe?

Tags: com, dll, winapi, exe, portability

I need to check programatically whether a given EXE binary is a COM, EXE or Win32.exe, is this possible through the Import Table? Where in the registry should I look to find out if a binary is registered for COM? This is specific to EXEs, as DLLs are not a problem for me.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

Comment: From now I am making this as practise. but I did'nt get any answer of my above statted question.

Comment: Ha, I read this and assumed it was a question about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file. Nevermind then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a DLL you can ask for its DllGetClassObject (AFAIK inprocess COM servers are required to export this function).

For exes, I am afraid you cant, at least not 100% sure. you may only apply heuristics such as checking if exe has typelibs in its resources (but keep in mind that it is not required).